# Dynamically create multiple forms in angular2

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am fetching some data from database and on the basis of number of results I want to create forms . For eg. If I am getting total 3 rows with columns as name,age and class . Then I need to create three form elements with name, age and class as form element. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FormArray to create multiple form groups.

With FormBuilder we can create a FormGroup for the FormControls. In the FormGroup define a variable as FormArray and dynamically add FormControls to that array.

```
public dataForm = FormGroup;
const dbData = // data from database eg. [{name:x, age: 8, class: A},..]
...
constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder
) {}
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataForm = this._fb.group({
       subFormList: this._fb.array([])
    });
    this.getValues();
}
getValues() {
   const control = <FormArray> this.dataForm.get('subFormList');
   for (row of this.dbData) {
      const temp = this._fb.group({
         name: [row['name']],
         age: [row['age']],
         class: [row['class']]
      });
      control.push(temp);
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you.